# Android: "Error: Invalid --tag default for the selected target."

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

After running

```
android create avd -f -a -s HVGA -n hudson_en-US_160_HVGA_android-20_armeabi-v7a -t android-20 --abi armeabi-v7a
```

I recieved the error message `Error: Invalid --tag default for the selected target.`

I have android-20, and armeabi-v7a installed through the SDK manager.
Does anybody have any ideas? I know it is the -g or --tag parameter but I can't find anything on it on google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
android create avd -f -a -s HVGA -n hudson_en-US_160_HVGA_android-20_armeabi-v7a -t android-20 --abi android-wear/armeabi-v7a
```

In case anyone else has the same issue with android-20 (Android 4.4W) turns out the abis are prefixed with android-wear the above should do the trick

Comment: How did you come to this solution? How to view the prefixes?

Comment: @Cleankod I made some improvements to answer your question

Comment: @Cleankod run `android list targets`

Comment: Should I use `android-wear` prefix if I want to target phones?

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet your trouble is the escaping on the dashes in the name, tag, and abi.  For instance, this works for me:

`android create avd --name nexus --target 3 --abi "default/x86"`

Instead, perhaps try:

`android create avd -f -a -s HVGA -n "hudson_en-US_160_HVGA_android-20_armeabi-v7a" -t "android-20" --abi "armeabi-v7a"`

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me. I'll keep trying. Thanks

Comment: Even with this command android create avd -f -a -s HVGA -n test -t android-20 --abi armeabi-v7a I get the same error

Comment: turns out that android-wear/armeabi-v7a is what the abi should have been. I am not sure why

Answer (score -1):

run android list targets, you can see ABIs, these ABIs hava prefix, so you must write prefix, 'default' can not write.